# How can I use RegistrySearch to check if a program is 32bit or 64bit

Tags: wix, registry, bootstrapper

I have a bootstrapper project that outputs an .EXE that should install a driver for a program in 32bit or 64bit depending on the program platform. I would like to do a RegistrySearch in the Bundle.*wxs* file to return if the program installed is x86 or x64. This is what I have so far:

```
<!--Check if program is x86 or x64-->
<util:RegistrySearch Id="Program_Platform" Variable="Program_Platform_Installed" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\[MY_COMPANY]\[PRODUCTNAME]\Platform" />                         
                                          
 <Chain>
    <MsiPackage Id="Program_Platform32" InstallCondition='NOT VersionNT64' SourceFile='E:\Products\[MY_COMPANY]\ISSUE_DISKS\Drivers\[DRIVER_NAME]\Setup.msi' />
    <MsiPackage Id="Program_Platform64" InstallCondition='VersionNT64' SourceFile='E:\Products\[MY_COMPANY]\ISSUE_DISKS_x64\Drivers\[DRIVER_NAME]\Setup.msi' />
 </Chain>
```

In the windows registry editor, I added a new *string* value called '*Platform*' and manually put in x64 as there was no variable there, or can it tell some other way?

To test this, I put this command into cmd: `E:\..\[DRIVER_NAME]>msiexec /i  setup.msi /L*v  c:\temp\imp.log` , but when I look at the output log file, there is a lot of text and I'm not entirely sure what I'm looking for to let me know if it worked.